# How to structure database for Group functionality?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm new at firebase and NoSQL data modelling, hence I am seeking recommendations on how to structure my db(firestore) for group functionality where users can create groups, specify roles to each other and also share messages.

I had this in mind:

```
Groups (collection)
    GroupId (document)
        name: value,
        description: value,
        createdOn: value,
        members: (array or map of uid's)
    GroupId (document)
    and so on...
```

Also, I am wondering how will users assign roles in this kind of structure?
Please criticise me for the limitations of the above structure and suggest your alternatives.

Open to all kinds of suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: Typically, in NoSQL, the structure if your data is determined by what queries you want to run. The proposed structure could work but what if a member of your group needs to be removed? To do that, you would have to read in the entire array, and then write it back out with that member removed (suggestion: don't use arrays). What if you want the members ordered in the structure? How do roles come into play since that's not in your structure? It's pretty broad and may not be answerable.

Comment: Okay got it, thank you so much.